# How to remove unwanted fields from Salesforce1 filters?

Tags: salesforce1-app, administration

On salesforce1 in list views there are buttons like **Filter**, **Sort** and **New**

[image]

When clicked on **Add Filter** it is showing all the fields which are visible to me. How to restrict the fields available for filters?